# I can't find all TR tags in a datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My dom is simply defined as:

```
sDom: 't',
```

My datatable name is:

```
dataTable: "#mainTable",
```

and I'm trying to find all TR tags in that datatable by using this jQuery selector:

```
var trs = $('#mainTable').children('tr');
```

But for some reason when I call the below code I get "0":

```
alert(trs.length);
```

Would anyone know why?

Comment: it's because they aren't children.. they are below the thead/tbody/tfoot

Comment: I also tried: $('#mainTable tbody tr') and nothing...

Comment: inspect the table.. are you sure the ID is mainTable?

Comment: can you show how you initialize the table?  is it $('#mainTable').datatable()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To access the rows in the table you must use the datatables function: `[datatable_object].$([selector])`

```
//Create datatable
var trs = $('#mainTable').dataTable();

//Get all rows from the trs table object.
var rows = trs.$("tr");
```

There are more examples under the $ section on http://www.datatables.net/api